# SNMPTT exec not working

Tags: linux, nagios, snmp

We're using SNMPTT in a Nagios environment. My MIB works for all events, but 1. I can't figure out what's going on.

When a trap comes in, I want it to execute a file, which will then handle the notification and Nagios alerting.

Here's the section from the MIB:

```
EVENT lgpEventConditionEntryAdded .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1 "Status Events" CRITICAL
FORMAT LIEBERT CUSTOM TRAP lgpEventConditionEntryAdded
EXEC /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pob_translate_liebert_trap.sh $r $s $2
SDESC
The device is reporting an alarm.
EDESC
```

My `pob_translate_liebert_trap.sh` file just does extra email debugging, then sends it to Nagios. Nothing really to see here.

Here's the result from the snmptt.debug log when a trap comes in matching `.1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1`

```
Processing file: #snmptt-trap-1468519738245030
Reading trap.  Current time: Thu Jul 14 14:32:38 2016

Raw trap passed from snmptrapd:
1468519738
<UNKNOWN>
UDP: [10.redacted]:65534->[170.redacted]
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 70:4:13:32.08
.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.1.12 12
.1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.2.12 .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19
.1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.3.12 70:4:13:32.05
.1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0 10.redacted
.1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.4.0 "public"
.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0 .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3

Items passed from snmptrapd:
value 0: 10.redacted
value 1: 10.redacted
value 2: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
value 3: 70:4:13:32.08
value 4: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
value 5: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1
value 6: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.1.12
value 7: 12
value 8: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.2.12
value 9: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19
value 10: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.3.12
value 11: 70:4:13:32.05
value 12: .1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0
value 13: 10.redacted
value 14: .1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.4.0
value 15: public
value 16: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.3.0
value 17: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3
Host IP address (10.redacted) could not be resolved by DNS.  Variable $r / $R etc will use the IP address
Agent IP address (10.redacted) is the same as the host IP, so copying the host name: 10.redacted

Trap received from 10.redacted: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1
0:              hostname
1:              ip address
2:              uptime
3:              trapname / OID
4:              ip address from trap agent
5:              trap community string
6:              enterprise
7:              securityEngineID        (snmptthandler-embedded required)
8:              securityName            (snmptthandler-embedded required)
9:              contextEngineID         (snmptthandler-embedded required)
10:             contextName             (snmptthandler-embedded required)
0+:             passed variables

Value 0: 10.redacted
Value 1: 10.redacted
Value 2: 70:4:13:32.08
Value 3: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1
Value 4: 10.redacted
Value 5: public
Value 6: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3
Value 7:
Value 8:
Value 9:
Value 10:
Agent dns name: 10.redacted
Ent Value 0 ($1): .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.1.12=12
Ent Value 1 ($2): .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.2.12=.1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19
Ent Value 2 ($3): .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.3.12=70:4:13:32.05

Exact match of trap found in EVENT hash table

Working with EVENT entry: .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1 => lgpEventConditionEntryAdded,Status Events,CRITICAL,
  No nodes defined for this entry so all nodes will match
  No MATCH entries defined for this entry

Trap defined, processing...


PREEXEC line(s):


FORMAT line:
Variable .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.3.12 with value 70:4:13:32.05
Variable .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.2.12 with value .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19
Variable .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.1.12 with value 12
LIEBERT CUSTOM TRAP lgpEventConditionEntryAdded
.1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.3.0.1 CRITICAL "Status Events" 10.redacted - LIEBERT CUSTOM TRAP lgpEventConditionEntryAdded

EXEC line(s):
Variable .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.3.12 with value 70:4:13:32.05
Variable .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.2.12 with value .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19
Variable .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.3.1.1.12 with value 12
EXEC command:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pob_translate_liebert_trap.sh 10.redacted CRITICAL .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19
```

Now, if I log in as user `snmptt` and run this command: `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/pob_translate_liebert_trap.sh 10.redacted CRITICAL .1.3.6.1.4.1.476.1.42.3.2.1.19` it works great.

Any insight on what is breaking down from this script not running when snmptt translates it? It looks like it **should** be running

Comment: The script is not executed at all? Can SNMPTT execute something else, e.g. EXEC /bin/echo "Trap from $r received" >>/tmp/snmptt.test

Comment: @L.R. Yeah it's exec'ing other OIDs with the same exec script fine. It's this exec block thats not working. Also, when I `su` to the snmptt user, i can exec it as well.

Comment: That's strange. Is there any substantial difference in environmental variables (`env`) when script is started by the snmptt process compared to situation when it is started manually as snmptt user?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in one of the "$*". Remove this one from parametr list and all will work fine.

This is a bug. Depends on a symbols in text of trap|oids.